# How to see files and folders in the remote repo server?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git.

I have set up a Git server on windows 7 machine and all our local repos run in linux machines.

I have created a bare repo in remote server(windows m/c) and then cloned it in the local m/c (linux)

In local machine I added few files (say README.txt and test.txt) and then commit and pushed it to remote repo (this was successful)

My question is (not sure if it is a valid question)

where can I find those files in the remote repo? (if I go to the remote repo I see hooks, info, objects, refs folder and config, decription and head files.)

Comment: Try pulling code in windows machine to get the latest code pushed from linux machine.

Comment: Your remote tracking branch is, after the moment you go a `git fetch`, a mirror copy of the branch on the remote which is being tracked.  Why do you want to access the file on the remote repository?

Comment: (1/2)scenario is 
Say I have a local repo test.git which contains Debug folder(this in turn contains lots of files among which some_example.elf file is also present), source folder and download.bat file. Now, everything is pushed to remote repo test.git
In the download.bat file I should give path to some_example.elf file to perform some operation.
I'm using jenkins to build this
I was confused which path to give, do I have to give local repo path (which doesn't makes sense) or remote repo path.

Comment: (2/2) if remote repo path where can i find the folder Debug in remote or does remote repo is checked out somewhere under temp to perform build operations
P.S. Please excuse my grammar. or if I did not make myself clear.